# what happens in this C++ program?

Tags: c++, cout, pointer-arithmetic

consider following program:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int num=345;
    std::cout<<"num " + num<<'\n';
}
```

When I run this program it displays F as an output. How? Is pointer arithmetic being performed here? If I use - sign instead of + then blank output appears.

Comment: std::cout contains a wrong concetenation....

Comment: @Downvoters: make a habit to specify reason for downvote. What's wrong in question?

Comment: @radscheit: I know it. I intentionally use + operator see what happens? How I got F as output?

Comment: Look at bku_drytt's answer, you got undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is undefined behavior, you happen to have the value of `F` when you go 345 past the start of the `"num "` array of `char`'s. This does not produce the same results on my local machine.

Comment: @shuttle87: yes now it makes sense.

Comment: The way I learned why this happens is that in C++ `"A" + 1 == "B"`

Comment: @McLeary [But it is not](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/03f73f096ccb6db0)

Comment: @McLeary Perhaps you meant `'A' + 1`.

Comment: @aslg thats right, my bad!

Comment: @rozina [Now it is](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7cfe0bf1f2039482).  I typed " instead of '.

Comment: @McLeary indeed it is :) However, there is no pointer arithmetic happening here, so it is not the same as OP's case.

Comment: @rozina agreed, my comment's intent was to show this peculiar thing C/C++ has that other languages don't have.

Comment: @pravasi I didn't downvote but I think your title is downvote worthy because of it being not descriptive at all.

Comment: @McLeary Why is it peculiar? Also, this happens in many other languages.

Comment: @JorenHeit I didn't mean to cause any trouble with my words. The peculiar part is that, in my way of seeing thing, the nature of C++ allows two apparently distinct types to be 'added' (char and int). I know it happens with other languages as well, but it may seem a little bit confusing. It was for me in the beginning at least.

Comment: @rozina: In the case of 'A' +1 you said no pointer arithmetic happens. Then what happens? Is it unspecified or undefined/ well defined behavior to perform 'A'+1?

Comment: @PravasiMeet the difference is that `"A"` is a `string`, and `'A'` is a `char`. And a character is no more than a single-byte integer (unlike a string). If you add one, you will simply increment its value by one. And in the ascii table 'B' (66) comes right after 'A' (65).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

String literal `"num "` is `const char[5]` which decays to `const char*` to which you are adding an offset.

The following piece of code is equivalent to what you are doing:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int num = 345;
    const char* c_str = "num ";
    std::cout << c_str + num << '\n';
}
```

**A:** You have undefined behaviour because you are accessing memory locations outside of the bounds of your array. You are violating memory safety.

Since `cout` will only stop printing once it finds a `'\0`' for c-strings, you could potentially keep printing until it does. You can't know when that value will next happen thus you have undefined behaviour as explained in **A**.

Comment: "because you are accessing memory locations outside of the bounds" Where did he do that?

Comment: @rozina Outside of the bounds of his array, yes. His array is const char[5], therefore his memory is from `char[0]` to `char[4]`, he is accessing `char[345]` which is not in his range, and could print anything from that location until the first `'\0'` character was found.

Answer (score 7):

Let's say you have your `"num"` string. In memory it may look like,

```
 0  1  2  3  4
[n][u][m][ ][\0]
```

When you print it, it will be used as a pointer. And now you add an offset of 345 to it.

```
 0  1  2  3  4   5  6  7     345
[n][u][m][ ][\0][?][?][?]....[F][?][?]
```

Your program may have printed more than just an F though, it stops on the first `\0` found. It's undefined behaviour because your program could print just about anything, and will access invalid memory adresses.

If your goal was to print an integer, then you could write

```
std::cout << "num" << num << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 6):

It's very instructive to compile with all warnings:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:6:25: warning: array subscript is above array bounds [-Warray-bounds]
     std::cout<<"num " + num<<'\n';

                         ^
```

See [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1e11c9c0cbb89946)

Essentially the compiler is telling you that you have done pointer arithmetic here on the underlying array that stores `"num "`. In essence `"num "` is an array that stores the characters needed for that string literal. When you perform arithmetic on it this decays to a `const char*` which you then add 345 to the pointer address. This memory address is outside the defined array and on *your specific machine* this happens to be the value `F`. This is however undefined behavior, the output could be something else entirely on a different machine.

Often these compiler warnings are the results of bugs, so paying attention to what the compiler is telling you is often very valuable.